Initution and ideas to find counterexamples related to functions
I find it hard to construct examples to disprove certain statements, does anyone have any ideas for such examples when disproving statements?
For example:

Let $X=C[0,1]$ be set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with metric $$
\begin{aligned}
d_\infty(f,g) &= \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)|, \\
d_2(f,g) &= \sqrt{\int_0^1(f(x)-g(x))^2\,dx}
\end{aligned}
$$

Is $S = \{f \in X: f(0) = 0\}$ closed in $(X, d_2)$?


Ans: False. Show $X\setminus S$ is not open. Take $f=1$, $f\in X\setminus S$. Want to find function in $B_{d_2}(f,r)$ but not in $X\setminus S$. For all $r \in (0,1)$, let $$
f_r(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{x}{r} & 0 \leq x \leq r, \\ 
1 & r < x \leq 1. 
\end{cases}
\tag{$a$}
$$
Since $f_r(0) = 0 \implies f_r \in S$. Moreover $d_2(f_r,f)<r\implies f_r\in B_{d_2}(f,r)$.
The functions $(a)$ seems not very straightforward. Can anyone give some ideas to derive these functions?
Thanks a lot!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
